# One-To-Many in Entity Framework: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property
>   values that define the referential constraints are not consistent
>   between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

I got this error when trying to update an existing object of the "Author" class.  One "Author" has many objects of the class "Book", and these are created and updated dinamically in the same Create/Edit View of the Author Model. Objects are created without any problem. Classes definition:

```
Public MustInherit Class Author
    <Key(), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)>
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String  
    Public Overridable Property Books() As ICollection(Of Book)
End Class

Public Class Book
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String    
    Public Property AuthorID As Integer
    Public Overridable Property Author As Author
End Class
```

After the Edit form is submitted, "Author" object pass to Edit POST method containing also edited info of the Books stored in the ICollection.Then, forementioned error is thrown in AuthorsController, Edit POST Method, when EntityState is modified (line 5):

```
<HttpPost()> _
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken()> _
Function Edit(ByVal author As Author) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        db.Entry(author).State = EntityState.Modified
        db.SaveChanges()
        Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Authors")
    End If
    Return View(author)
End Function
```

Any help on this? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the value from the database 1st then update the values.
I suspect what is going on is the posted author has no books once bound but has existing books (Books collection is empty but has books linked by foreign key in the DB)

Try something along the lines of:

```
var model = db.Authours.Find(author.ID)
//update the values or use something like Automapper
db.SaveChanges()
```